# Cordova android build error: Error executing "ant clean -f ..."

Tags: android, cordova

I get this error, when i try to build and run an cordova project on an android device:

```
Running app on platform "android" via command "***/Documents/***/App/platforms/android/cordova/run" --device
[Error: An error occurred while running the android project.
/***/Documents/***App/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error executing "ant clean -f /***/Documents/***/App/platforms/android/build.xml": Build failed
```

Any suggestion on fixing this problem?

Comment: Clean your project and try to build again.

Comment: @Siddharth Vyas: Didn't fix it ..

"Buildfile: /Volumes/Mac OS X II/Mathias/Documents/knockout-fest/App/platforms/android/build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
 [checkenv] Installed at /Applications/Android/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: KnockoutFestival
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-pre-clean:

clean:
[getlibpath] Library dependencies:
[getlibpath] No Libraries
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second"

But when i run cordova run afterwards i still get the same error as in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if "adb devices" command works. If it doesn't work ensure "android-tools-adb" is installed and then run the "adb devices" command. Rerun the build after that.

Comment: Hey @Maniappan i have got http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222461/build-error-running-cordova-platform-add-android error in win xp. Could you please tell me how can i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I upgraded the CLI cordova (via npm) to 3.3.1 but forgot up update my project to the corresponding version.  This fixed it for me:

```
cordova platform update android
```

Comment: thank you, that worked for me. In my case, I wanted to run a starter project downloaded from microsoft azure.