# Build Error running cordova platform add android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to create an Android PhoneGap project according to the following link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html

But, when I run the command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

I get the following output:

```
Checking Android requirements...
Creating android project...
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.example.hello
    Name: HelloWorld
    Android target: android-17
Building cordova-3.2.0-rc1.jar

{ [Error: Command failed: 
BUILD FAILED
/path/to/adt/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/path/to/adt/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 127

Total time: 1 second
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
]
```

Does anybody know how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have exactly the same error message. 
in my case, the lib32stdc++ was not installed in my ubuntu, after installation, all work as intended.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Hope this could resolve your problem.

Comment: @Darktalker could you please help me with the path, because I did everything and still getting the same error.

Comment: if you are still getting this kind of error, try install lib32bz2-1.0 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 as well.

Comment: FYI, on Centos (yum-based systems), I had to execute `yum install libstdc++.i686` to workaround the problem.

Answer (score 8):

For me, on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit, this was fixed by installing 32bit libz:

```
sudo aptitude install libz1:i386
```

I found this by:

- Examining the build.xml and find that it was trying to run aapt
- Finding aapt in the android-sdk-linux/build-tools/18.1.1/build-tools directory and running it

  libz.so.1 not found

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! The last piece to a frustrating puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge ,first of all you have to download the cord-ova plugin from 
[cord-ova](http://phonegap.com/install/)
and after you have to install the plugin eclipse by going to help-->Install new software by typing phone-gap.
In eclipse Press Ctrl+N and select phone-gap and while creating the project choose the your cord-ova which you have download give the path up to of cord-ova (there is radio button to choose that ,by default it choose 1.X.X version instead of that choose your latest version below that )

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to Ant. There is no build system.

Download and install Ant.

Make sure you configure the system PATH correctly as defined in the installation document.

Comment: Actually, ant is already installed. When I run the command "ant" from the terminal, it works.
Also, when I type "android" from the terminal, it works.

What I could understand from your answer was: Add /path/to/ant/bin to PATH. Am I correct?

Comment: You need to setup a new PATH variable ANT_HOME with the path of Ant.

Comment: When I give "ant build", I get "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed"
But, when I give "ant build" inside to /path/to/adt/sdk/tools/ant, I get:
Buildfile: /home/arthur/development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource anttasks.properties. It could not be found.
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.