# Error building android platform with phonegap

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova

I have phonegap 3.2.0-0.17.0 installed on Ubuntu 12.10.

For some reason, when I try to build the android platform to my local project on phonegap, I get the following error:

```
> phonegap local build android

[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
Path: platforms/android
Package: com.package.project_name
Name: project_name
Android target: android-17
Building cordova-3.2.0.jar


{ [Error: Command failed:
BUILD FAILED
/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 127

Total time: 1 second
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

Here my JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME & PATH configuration for any suggestion:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.2
export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools:/path/to/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools:${ANT_HOME}/bin
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: It has been already asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222461/build-error-running-cordova-platform-add-android.